How to remove grid lines of lithology data downloaded from Bhukhosh?
I have downloaded the Lithologic Data for a certain district from Bhukhosh, Geological Survey of India (GSI). The data obtained comes in .shp format. However there are certain grid lines present in the data which I want to remove. The grid lines are present in the data itself.
I tried converting the vector file to raster, and again converting the converted raster file to vector. However there is some minor loss of area after conversion and the converted raster to vector image doesn't look good enough. Thus, I am looking for some methods or techniques to remove the gridlines.
Can you suggest any methods to remove these grid lines?
The image for the same is given below.


Dissolve based on lithology type.

Just to expand on @GBG comment...  It looks as though those lines may not actually be in the data explicitly, but rather the data is all divided into tiles, which are then visible like grid lines.  If that is the case, then dissolving the data (as GBG suggested) should resolve the issue.  Use the Dissolve tool:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm

You may need to Repair Geometry first, and possibly afterwards.

A solution as mentioned in the comments is to dissolved the geometries using the dissolve tool. This of cause creates a new dataset that brings it's own challenges such as being massively multi-part and would require you to maintain and document it.
Another approach is to dissolve the boundaries using cartographic techniques, a useful blog using ArcMap discusses this approach here.
